# Apache Camel Response Type Mismatch for Multiple Apache Camel REST Services

Tags: kotlin, apache-camel

I am testing out a contrived REST API using the Apache Camel REST DSL.

I am attempting to POST to the **/login** route shown below and getting an unexpected response.

Here is my REST configuration and REST services.

```
    restConfiguration().apply {
        component = "undertow"
        port = "8082"
        bindingMode = RestBindingMode.json
        dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
        apiContextPath = "api-doc"
        apiProperty("api.title", "Online Bookstore API")
        apiProperty("cors", "true")
        apiProperty("host", "localhost:8082")
        apiProperty("base.path", "bookstore/api")
    }

    rest("/login")
        .post()
            .consumes("application/json")
            .description("User Authentication.")
            .type(LoginRequest::class.java)
            .outType(AuthenticatedResponse::class.java)
        .route().routeId("login-route")
            .to("direct:processLoginRequest")

    rest("/registration")
        .post()
            .consumes("application/json")
            .description("Register a new Gutenberg customer")
            .type(CustomerRegistration::class.java)
        .route().routeId("registration-route")
            .to("direct:processRegistrationRequest")

    rest("/customer/payment-method")
        .post()
            .consumes("application/json")
            .description("Setup a new customer payment method")
            .type(NewPaymentMethod::class.java)
        .route().routeId("payment-method-route")
            .to("direct:processNewPaymentMethod")

    rest("/books")
        .get()
            .description("Get a list of books available for purchase.")
            .outType(Array<BookResponse>::class.java)
        .route().routeId("books-route")
            .to("direct:retrieveBooks")

    rest("/orders/purchase")
        .post()
            .description("Creates a new order")
            .type(NewBookOrder::class.java)
            .outType(OrderResponse::class.java)
        .route().routeId("order-route")
            .to("direct:processOrder")
}
```

This is the response I get:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.example.camel.messages.outbound.OrderResponse] value failed for JSON property id due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter id which is a non-nullable type
>    at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 4, column: 1] (through reference chain: com.example.camel.messages.outbound.OrderResponse["id"])

Notice that it seems to be skipping the *outType* defined for **/login** and using the *outType* for **/orders/purchase**.

I must have something configured wrong here. Any ideas? I have tried multiple ways and get the same result.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin, though you might separate your `RestDefinitions` as shown [here](https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/latest/languages/kotlin.html#_rest_endpoints)

Comment: I did implement this using Kotlin but this is mostly irrelevant as I am still using the Java DSL. I applied the Java DSL equivalent of your linked example (rest config per route) and I still get the same result. It just seems that the REST DSL is not equipped to handle multiple _outType_ and _type_ for that matter.

Comment: Our general setup is a bit different than yours. We abstracted the `restConfiguration` definition into an [abstract class](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/api/BaseAPIRouteBuilder.java) which the [respective routes inherit from](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/api/SampleFileRoute.java). While this samples are taken from a tech-demo and don't utilize Camel's `type` or `outType`, our productive code at least uses a couple of `outType`s

Comment: Just a warning if you try to learn from the code: this tech-demo has a serious bug in its `SpringConfig` in regards to the `HalDataFormatResolver` defined there which will only work if all of the routes want to use `hal+json` as otherwise the configuration that kicked in first will win, depending on the route that got invoked first. We fixed that already some time ago in the productive code, this fix did not make its way into this tech-demo so far though.